# How do I prevent villager children from disappearing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Jeff and Michelle are two villagers in my manually built village. I have them locked in a glass room in order to grow the village. They had a child and it was about 15 minutes old when it disappeared. The Minecraft wiki states that a villager cannot de-spawn, and that it can only forget about its village after leaving its boundary for 6 seconds. I am on peaceful difficulty, all three of the villagers were in a sealed room, I left to work on the Village and I returned to find the their child had disappeared.

[image]

This is the room I had locked the family inside. It has more than enough beds and two job site blocks (lecterns). Both of the villagers are named via nametag (Jeff and Michelle), because it was the easiest way to catch a zombie villager without it despawning. I have read up on this and most sources say that this shouldn't matter. So what happened to the child? I highly doubt it suffocated or teleported outside, as there is lots of free space around the beds. And its on peaceful so there is no way they could have died to a zombie. Do villagers die due to starvation or does that just affect willingness like I've read? How do I prevent this from happening again and what are the possible reasons it happened?

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to get out or for a zombie to get in? Not even a diagonal corner? Zombies can punch villagers through those. Is there any water nearby? Anything else that could damage something? Also, no, villagers can not starve.

Comment: @FabianRöling No there was absolutely no exit for the villagers, not even a door. They were walled in completely

Comment: I want this to get on Hot questions, just because how morbid the title sounds

Comment: There appears to be a hole in the floor one block to the left of the leftmost villager: what is that? Also, do the villagers have access to the soulsand? Maybe it suffocated in it, because I think that happens to small mobs when they walk on it.

Comment: @Nik3141 That is a chest in the ground. Its on the same level as the rest of the floor. Also i saw the villager child walking on the soul sand earlier. It didn't appear to take any damage at the time.

Comment: Never mind about the soulsand that's only silverfish and endermites.

Comment: Hmm… almost feels like it belongs over here… a real murder mystery https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I think I've found out the reason for the mysterious disappearance! I watched the village children the next time one was produced. So since the Village and Pillage update (i think) baby villagers tend to jump on beds! Now the problem with this is that if a villager grows up while they are jumping on a bed and there is not enough space above them they will grow directly into the roof and suffocate :D . So I think this is what happened to Jeff and Michelle's child because when their next child grew up this exactly happened! An easy solution is a higher roof or no roof at all.

Comment: Why do you show a happy face when you found out they suffocated? (scared)

Comment: @L.F. Because I discovered the reason of their horrible demise! :D

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because of a lack of space for the villagers to move freely.  You can find excellent tutorials for villager spawners on the minecraft wiki if you need ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think I have found the reason they were disappearing. If you see my above answer I think my results are conclusive.

Comment: Lack of space isn't a reason for them to _despawn_; that only affects the ability of _naturally-respawning_ mobs to spawn, and once they're there, they can freely walk into places too small for them to spawn